# Delete Fields Where a Null Value Appeard

Tags: mysql, sql

[image: blank]

So, how do i delete this? I acidentially wrote about 1,500 blank records with prefix null and code = 0

I tried this query and it does nothing:

```
DELETE FROM Course where prefix IS NULL and code = 0;
```

The feedback I get is 0 results were deleted.

Anyone?

Answer (score 4):

`prefix` probably isn't `NULL` it's an empty string.

Try the following and see if it yields the desired results.

```
SELECT * FROM Course WHERE prefix = '' AND code = 0;
```

If so, update your `DELETE` statement at your own risk ;)

Comment: This returns non-legit database records with the empty values

Comment: So you're good to go then. **Richard** has the `DELETE` query. It's always good practice to run a `SELECT` first though.

Comment: Perfect this works! In 5 mins I'll give you the check - it wont allow me to :)

Answer (score 1):

I bet that prefix is an empty string.  Try this:

```
delete from course where prefix = '' and code = 0
```